# Correct way to use encryption in Xamarin shared project

Tags: c#, encryption, xamarin, xamarin.forms, pcl-crypto

I'm currently developing a Xamarin Forms Project and I need to use a few encryption methods that would normally be available through namespace System.Security.Cryptography namely *RSACryptoServiceProvider*. So far I have been using PCLCrypto nuget package to use other methods such MD5 hashing but I haven't figured out how to use RSA specifically. I was also wondering if it would be better to implement those methods directly on each native Project instead and then use them on the shared one instead of using the nuget.

Any thoughts on this? If someone could point me towards some documentation for PCLCrypto equivalent to what I need it would be fine as well, I just need some lights on this concern and some clarification since I've read some other questions but there isn't really a consensus.

Comment: Check this link, looks that is already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327069/encrypt-string-using-pclcrypto

Comment: Thank you, it will be useful! I was hoping to find someone who could point me to exact documentation because it is lacking. At least if you would like to implement something different I don't think it is very...nice...to always have to consult stack overflow. But as I said thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Nuget package for Cryptography is not PCL friendly, you might want to utilize Xamarin.Forms DependencyService. You can implement those Crypto methods natively and just call the actual implementations via the DependencyService.

1. Create an interface in your PCL (e.g. ICrypto).
2. Create a method in that interface that, for example, validates a password (e.g. bool PasswordValid).
3. Add the Nuget package for System.Security.Cryptography to your native project.
4. Create a class in your native code that will implement that interface (e.g. Crypto_Android) and have an implementation for the method (e.g. bool PasswordValid)
5. Call this code from your PCL via DependencyService. The syntax would be something like this:

bool valid = DependencyService.Get< ICrypto >().PasswordValid(password);

NOTE: For the code on actual Cryptography you can check the PCLCrypto Github link provided above by Tifa.

A simple DependencyService example can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/battery-info/).

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. It seems to me like the best way to use encryption in a PCL Project.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if AES could be interesting for you but maybe you can take at look at this sample.

```
byte[] keyMaterial;
byte[] data;
var provider = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);

// The IV may be null, but supplying a random IV increases security.
// The IV is not a secret like the key is.
// You can transmit the IV (w/o encryption) alongside the ciphertext.
var iv = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(provider.BlockLength);

byte[] cipherText = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, data, iv);

// When decrypting, use the same IV that was passed to encrypt.
byte[] plainText = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, cipherText, iv);
```

[Source: PCLCrypto Github](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto/wiki/Crypto-Recipes)

Maybe this link could help you with crypto on Xamarin.Forms project ([Using Cryptography in Portable Xamarin Forms (Windows Phone, Android and IOS)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4088a7/using-cryptography-in-portable-xamarin-formswindows-phone/))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really needed to use RSA as I described in my question. I am, though, taking this sample I had previously found in the same place as a guideline for the other methods because as I mentioned there isn't any other sample regarding RSA and a few other methods.